# fine tune spacy word vectors

Tags: spacy, word-embedding

This question is of a more conceptual type.
I was using the pre-trained word-vectors of spacy (the `de_core_news_md` model).
The problem is that I have a lot of domain specific words which all get a 0-vector assignet and overall the results are in gerneral not too good.
I was wondering how one should proceed now.
should I try to fine tune the existing vectors? If so, how would one approach that?
Or, should I just not use the pre-trained word vectors of spacy and create my own?

Edit:
I want to fine tune the pre trained vectors. I've read, that I could train the already trained model again but on my data. Now my question is, how to do that. When I use spacy, i just load the model. Should I download the vectors of spacy and train a gensim model with them and afterwards again with my vectors? Or is there a better way?

Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: You can start with loading vectors of a pre-trained spacy model and generate your weights using `spacy pretrain` route. If you are still not satisfied with the weights, I'd suggest to look at pre-trained transformer models as an alternative. It really depends on the domain, your downstream goals or what you are achieving to do with your language model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've read into spacy petrain but I think this is something else, since im not training in any way. I just got the vectors from a pretrained  spacy model and compare them afterwards. Or do you mean I should pretrain the model im using? Thanks!